# Gmaps4Rails - Creating polylines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have an issue with this wonderful gem gmaps4rails.
Is it possible to print on the map a polyline that doesn't have between its points a location that it's not in the markers list?

To be more clear, I add this code, taken from the HTML page created by Rails:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
    function gmaps4rails_init() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/src/infobox.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    Gmaps4Rails.map_options.type = 'TERRAIN';
    Gmaps4Rails.map_options.auto_adjust = true;
    Gmaps4Rails.initialize();
    Gmaps4Rails.markers = [
        {"latitude": "41.97", "longitude": "12.67", "description": "DEPARTURE DESCRIPTION HERE", "title": "TITLE HERE"}, 
        {"latitude": "45.58", "longitude": "12.57", "description": "ARRIVE DESCRIPTION HERE", "title": "TITLE HERE"}
    ];
    Gmaps4Rails.create_markers();
    Gmaps4Rails.polylines = [
        [
            {"latitude": "41.97", "longitude": "12.67"}, 
            {"latitude": "42.78", "longitude": "12.6"}, 
            {"latitude": "45.58", "longitude": "12.57"}
        ]
    ];
    Gmaps4Rails.polylines_conf.strokeColor = '#444444';
    Gmaps4Rails.create_polylines();
    if(typeof gmaps4rails_callback == 'function') { gmaps4rails_callback(); }
    }
    window.onload = gmaps4rails_init;
</script>
```

On the map I want only the start point (41.97, 12.67) end the end point (45.58, 12.57) displayed as markers. 
But I also want to create a polyline from the start pont to the end point: this polyline has to pass from another intermediate point (42.78, 12.6).

The problem is that the displayed polyline on the map is wrong: the line goes from the first point to the third pont without passing through the second one.

So, my question is: do I have to include as markers all the points of the polyline?

EDIT: from this page https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Display-Everything! it seems clear that you can display a polyline even if its points are not in the markers list.
So, why my polyline is not displayed correctly?

Comment: Since it was a mistake, I guess you could close this question.